# How to make an advanced search query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to built a free matrimonial site where the homepage holds a simple form with some textboxes & dropdowns and a button for search.

When clicked it takes the visitor to another page along with query strings of all fields.

I used the following stored procedure to show search result.
The parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cat", cat);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subcat", subcat == "-1" ? "-1" : "," + subcat);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", state);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city == "-1" ? "-1" : "," + city);
```

---

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchGetAdPageWise]  
       ,@cat INT
       ,@subcat NVARCHAR(10)
       ,@state INT
       ,@city NVARCHAR(10) 
    AS  

    BEGIN  
          SET NOCOUNT ON;  

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER  
            (  
                  ORDER BY a.ad_type ASC,NEWID()
            )AS RowNumber  
      ,a.Id
      ,a.ad_title
      ,b.Name a_state
      ,a.ad_brief  
      ,a.ad_pic    
    INTO #Results  
    FROM [tbl_ads] a LEFT JOIN tbl_state b ON a.ad_state=b.Id

 WHERE (a.ad_cat=@cat OR a.ad_cat='-1' OR a.ad_cat='') 
AND ((a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat+'%' OR a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat) OR a.ad_subcat='-1' OR a.ad_subcat='') 
AND (a.ad_state=@state OR a.ad_state='-1' OR a.ad_state='')  
AND ((a.ad_city LIKE N'%'+@city+'%' OR a.ad_city LIKE N'%'+@city) OR a.ad_city='-1' OR a.ad_city='')
```

The problem is I am stuck with OR & AND

if I use OR then it will show lots of irrelevant result.

if I use AND then what if any of the search query is empty.

Sorry I am new to this and my question might be too childish for you friends.

Another question if its the best & secure way to do so ? if not then how can I improve it.

Comment: Looks like the commas could cause an issue, the ones in the parameters: "," + subcat. I would assume that's supposed to be just subcat since you're comparing it to the contents of the column ad_subcat.

Comment: @Mike Use default values on your table where appropriate.

Comment: {a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat+'%' OR a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat}  - the second part is unnecessary here, what it looks for should be picked up by the first part

Comment: @JamesZ I want to filter my search result like this site: [link](http://www.imoveisemexposicao.com.br/imoveis-venda-guarulhos-residencial-casa)

Comment: @JamesZ This is my full description about this question [Optional filtering](http://forums.asp.net/p/2044843/5892528.aspx?Advanced+Search+Query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly data do you need to filter, but I think that you can try to use `...OR @var = ''` in following:

```
WHERE (a.ad_cat=@cat OR a.ad_cat='-1' OR a.ad_cat='') 
AND ((a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat+'%' OR a.ad_subcat LIKE N'%'+@subcat) OR a.ad_subcat='-1' OR @subcat='') 
AND (a.ad_state=@state OR a.ad_state='-1' OR @state='')  
AND ((a.ad_city LIKE N'%'+@city+'%' OR a.ad_city LIKE N'%'+@city) OR a.ad_city='-1' OR @city='')
```

Comment: This is my full description about this question [Optional filtering](http://forums.asp.net/p/2044843/5892528.aspx?Advanced+Search+Query)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I search logic can be hard. If I were you, I might try something like this. It should always return a set number of results(in my case 10 rows), the more relevant results will come first

```
SELECT TOP 10 * --or any number of rows
FROM
(
     SELECT TOP 10 *,1 AS result_order
     FROM yourTable
     WHERE 1=1 AND 2=2

     UNION ALL

     SELECT TOP 10 *,2 AS result_order
     FROM yourTable
     WHERE 1=1 OR 2=2
)
ORDER BY result_order
```

Comment: This is my full description about this question [Optional filtering](http://forums.asp.net/p/2044843/5892528.aspx?Advanced+Search+Query)